# Mysql Assigning attribute via trigger based on a radius of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm once again asking for your help!

I have been setting up a database for the first time during these past couple of days, in order to learn mysql. Starting with, from what I have been told a simple platform like a Webshop.

Now I have made the database with functioning relations, stored procedures some basic triggers like assigning a default roleID to every new customer.

But now I'm trying to see if it's possible to add a discountID based on the current date being either on or between the start_date AND end_date column attributes.

For example DiscountID= 'Christmass', Start_date='2022-12-10', End_date = '2022-12-26'.

My first thought was using a trigger with a IF ELSE.

But I'm not really sure how to realize this just yet.

```
 drop trigger if exists before_order;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_order
    BEFORE INSERT ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
            IF  order_date.orders = between Start_date.discounts  AND End_date.discounts
            SET NEW.DiscountID =;
            ELSE 
            SET New.DiscountID= 'No Discount';
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now this doesn't work but might help express what I'm after.

Any idea's or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: *some basic triggers like assigning a default roleID to every new customer.* Why trigger? DEFAULT column property will do the same. *My first thought was using a trigger with a IF ELSE.* Obviousy incorrect. Your discounts table will store a lot of rows - hence you'd retrieve all matched discount rows by the data within the discount dates range then select one of them by some criteria.

Comment: order_date.orders = between Start_date.discounts  AND End_date.discounts ? none of these look right correct syntax is <tablename>.<columnname> and assuming discounts is a table you need to invoke it and check against new.order_date And is CHRISTMASS significant at all or just fluff. Please add table definitions, sample data and expected outcome all as text,

Comment: It's worth you rereading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @P.Salmon , thanks that indeed is a helpful article!

Akina that's the thing, I was hoping to be able to create 1 trigger to determine if the current date matches the discountID's dates.  I guess you could create multiple triggers for each specific date.

Comment: I guess you could create multiple triggers for each specific date. - a) You can't b)why would you think that. If you can write a select query to do what you want then it's not a big leap to a trigger.

Comment: @P.Salmon I think I'm not really clear on what I am trying to accomplish. 

There are discounts in the discounts table. 
These have a start_date and a end_date. 

With a trigger you can automate certain processes and I'm trying to figure out if there's a trigger that can  automatically apply the right discountID based on currentdate(orderdate) and the start + end date and or any date in between.

if cur date = or in-between start_date, end_date than orders discoudID = ID1,ID2, ID3 or ID4.